# Does changing mouse speed on Windows 11 impact in-game mouse sensitivity?

Tags: pc, windows-11

So I was playing around with my mouse speed recently, when suddenly I wondered: is this changing my mouse sensitivity in games I play (*VALORANT*, *The Finals*, *The Division 2*, *Noita*, to name a few)? Would it only change the mouse sensitivity in some games (not necessarily the games I listed), or would this happen everywhere (if it happens at all)(not necessarily the games I listed)?

Answer (score 1):

It is commonly understood to CSGO players that the mouse speed setting in windows DOES affect in-game sensitivity. Most mouse-sensitivity guides for CSGO recommend a standard of setting it to 6 - the middle setting - before doing the rest of the calibration.

For example, [this article](https://coda.io/@zack-aman/finding-your-perfect-cs-go-mouse-sensitivity) says

> Most CS:GO pro and other esports players stick to the same default Windows mouse settings (6/11 for Windows sensitivity), but that is just personal preference.

Comment: My mouse speed is at 6, but the maximum speed is 20, not 11.

Comment: @SlightlyPsychotic weird, that's in the standard windows mouse speed interface? It goes up to 20?

Comment: Yeah, it is. If I drag the little slider all the way to right, it shows 20: [![photo][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgbhO.png

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about changing the actual DPI of your mouse then yeah it would change the sensitivity in game. If you're talking about a way to alter the speed of the mouse directly in Windows 11 then I would assume it would change the way windows is interpreting the mouse inputs and thus altering the speed in game. But I'd give it a try.

Comment: not actual DPI, just the mouse speed setting in Windows.